# Filtering a json type in a django model

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql, django-models

I have a JSON field in a PostgreSQL 9.3 database.  I'd like to be able to access it through a Django model.  I've taken a look at [django-jsonfield](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jsonfield/) and jsonfield; however these do little besides fetching the field and calling json dumps.  They lack the ability to filter on the field, i.e. make use of operators like ->>.  I'd like to do something akin to:

```
thebusiness = Business.objects.filter(data->>primaryKey=myBusinessID)
```

Are there any implementations of this, or do I have to roll out my own?  It seems strange that such a great database feature would lack any ORM support.

Comment: django-jsonfield doesn't store data as Postgres's native JSON type. You'll need to find an implementation that does that, for a start (or write your own).

Comment: Good point!  I've updated my question to more generally ask "How can do?"  I just want to find a way to filter using a model.